# Why can't I manage to get post data from html form send to express.js?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post, express

I have this code of server.js, I am really new to this.
I try to get what the html form send to node.js server (localhost)

**server.js**

```
//initialing the website


var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req, res){//get,put,post,delete   

res.sendFile('C:\\work\\translator\\startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3\\index.html');
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/css'));
app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/img'));
app.use("/font-awesome", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/font-awesome'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/js'));
app.use("/less", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/less'));
app.use("/mail", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/mail'));
app.use("/fonts", express.static(__dirname + '/startbootstrap-freelancer-1.0.3/fonts'));
    });


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});


//sending mail with gmail


app.post('/contact', function (req, res) { 

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'my_email',
        pass: 'my_password'
    }
});

  transporter.sendMail({
    from:  'user@email.com',
    to: 'myemail@email.com',
    subject: 'contact',
    text:  'hello world'
});
 });
```

**The Html form**

```
<form name="sentMessage" action="/contact" method="post" id="contact" novalidate>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone">
<textarea rows="5" class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">send</button>
```

I tried `req.params`, `req.body.email` and all kind of things to get the email in the email field but it says: "email undefiend", it's seems that somehow the server.js doesn't get the values/ parameters or something...

Answer (score 0):

Express is pretty minimal out of the box.You need to add body parser middleware to handle forms. Like this:

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser